# How to solve ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.81'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```python
# Body Mass Index Calculator

def BMI_calculator( ):
    name = input('Enter your name: ')
    weight_kg = int(input('Enter your weight in kg: '))
    height_m = int(input('Enter your height in meters: '))
    print('The BMI for ' + name + ' is: ')
    BMI = int(weight_kg) / height_m ** 2
    return BMI

print(BMI_calculator())
```

My error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "F:/Programming/Python 3 Tutorials/Tuturial/Automate the boring stuff with python/Others BMI_calculator.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(BMI_calculator())
  File "F:/Programming/Python 3 Tutorials/Tuturial/Automate the boring stuff with python/Others/BMI_calculator.py", line 7, in BMI_calculator
    height_m = int(input('Enter your height in meters: '))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.67'
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: add the error you are getting in your question

Comment: Your height (in m), should probably be a float, not an int

Comment: You should ask for height in cm so you can use integer type. All you need to change is `BMI = int(weight_kg) / (height_cm / 100) ** 2`

Comment: Because `1.81` is a `float()`, not an `int()`. Change all your `int()`s to `float()`s and it will work.

Comment: THE ERROR AM GETTING >>>>>>>>>>>>>>                                           
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/Programming/Python 3 Tutorials/Tuturial/Automate the boring stuff with python/Others/BMI_calculator.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(BMI_calculator())
  File "F:/Programming/Python 3 Tutorials/Tuturial/Automate the boring stuff with python/Others/BMI_calculator.py", line 7, in BMI_calculator
    height_m = int(input('Enter your height in meters: '))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.67'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: @KennyTMuleJnr please don't put updates in the comments, but directly in your code

Comment: @KennyTMuleJnr one more suggestion, don't put spaces in folder/file names. It will cause you lots of headache in the future

Comment: @KennyTMuleJnr sure thing. If you feel my answer works for you be sure to accept it

Answer (score 1):

First of, next time be sure to explain what problems you're running into, something like this:

> I'm having trouble converting my input into numbers, when I run it, I get this error:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/Users/Nathan/.PyCharmCE2019.2/config/scratches/scratch_35.py", line 13, in
>
> ```
> print(BMI_calculator())
> ```
>
> File "C:/Users/Nathan/.PyCharmCE2019.2/config/scratches/scratch_35.py", line 8, in BMI_calculator
>
> ```
> height_m = int(input('Enter your height in meters: '))
> ```
>
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1.81'

The problem is that your input (in meters) is going to be something like `1.81`, you cannot convert that to an integer (because of the `.`), so instead convert it to a float, like this:

```
height_m = float(input('Enter your height in meters: '))
```

**On another note**
Your BMI calculator asks for my name, which is a little weird because you don't need my name to calculate my BMI. If I were to rewrite your code, I'd do something like:

```
# Body Mass Index Calculator

def BMI_calculator(weight_kg, height_m):
    BMI = int(weight_kg / height_m ** 2)
    return BMI

# Only run this code if your run this file
# This allows for easy importing of BMI_calculator in other files
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Get the inputs to your function
    name = input('Enter your name: ')
    weight_kg = float(input('Enter your weight in kg: '))
    height_m = float(input('Enter your height in meters: '))

     # Calculate BMI
    bmi = BMI_calculator(weight_kg=weight_kg, 
                         height_m=height_m)

    # Print the results
    print(f'The BMI for {name} is: {bmi}')
```

The f-string (`f'lalaal {variable}'`) prints the value of the variable directly into the string. It makes your life easier to do it this way and it's more readable.

Comment: about the name its just for record sake but thanks very much have gotten the point.

Comment: weight is still converted to int after input then converted to int and than divided by which will convert it to float in python3 (by the new implicit type conversion)

Comment: It is important to notice that [`f-strings`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) are available only in Python 3.6+.

Comment: `weight_kg` must be a `float()` also. People have weights like `90.5 Kg` as well. And why call `bmi  = BMI_calculator(weight_kg=weight_kg, height_m=height_m)` since the parameters are already in the order the function expects them? Just do `bmi = BMI_calculator(weight_kg, height_m)`.

Comment: @Lee I've changed weight as well to float

Comment: @accdias I always put the parameter names in there, I think it's a good habit to get into early on with easy functions because with more complicated stuff it becomes really valuable

Comment: @Nathan, that's not Pythonic. You only do that for `kwargs` parameters. It is like call `range(start=0, stop=10, step=1)` when you can simply do `range(10)` or, to be concise with my example, `range(0, 10, 1)`. Oh! And you still have a hanging `int()` on your function definition.

Comment: @accdias I think the `int` is supposed to be there because the bmi should always be an int

Comment: @accdias it is pythonic because this is an example for a beginner. It's better to always do it and then later learn when not to, than to never do it (and never get into the habit of doing it)

Comment: @Nathan, [`BMI`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_mass_index) is an index and there is nothing saying it must be an `int()`. IMHO, it is better expressed as a `float()` rounded to a few decimal places.

Comment: @accdias as you say it's an index. It's only used for a rough estimation to somebodies health. If you google images of BMI indexes there's literally not a single image that uses a float

Comment: Did you check the the link above? Wikipedia links to a ton of other scientific papers and all of them express the index as a float round to a one or two decimal places. The definition of underweight, for example, is a `BMI < 18.5` and that looks A LOT like a float for me.

Comment: Quoting [World Health Organization](https://www.who.int/gho/ncd/risk_factors/bmi_text/en/): "To achieve optimum health, the median body mass index for an adult population should be in the range of 21 to 23 kg/m2, while the goal for individuals should be to maintain body mass index in the range 18.5 to 24.9 kg/m2. There is increased risk of co-morbidities for body mass index 25.0 to 29.9, and moderate to severe risk of co-morbidities for body mass index greater than 30. "

Comment: @accdias clearly the reason 29.9 is used is to stress that >= 30 is bad

Comment: @accdias "Did you check the link above": there is no link above

Comment: On my comment, `BMI` is a link to the article on Wikipedia. And if `29.9` "is used to stress that >= 30 is bad" your function, by using integers to express the index, can lead to an wrong evaluation, don't you think? Anyway, it is up to you to think about it. That was just my 2 cents trying to improve your answer.

Comment: @accdias I missed that. Either way. We're talking about an estimator used to predict health. Adding a decimal value adds no new information and suggests an accuracy that is not present. The difference in weight between measuring in the morning  and afternoon (for me) is 3% and puts me in a different BMI.